# find out who picked up the phone

Tags: tcl, voip, voice, ivr

I am developing tcl ivr on a cisco solution. My question is: in a tcl script when a call is placed for a group of numbers (hunt pilot), how can we determine who (which number) picked up the phone?

Is there any way we can do it in the tcl script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/voice/tcl/developer/guide/tclivrv2_ch3.html#wp1049954:

> If multiple destination numbers are specified, the `leg setup` command places the call to all the specified numbers simultaneously (causing all the destination phones to ring at the same time). When the first destination phone is answered, the call is connected and the remaining calls are disconnected. (This is called *blast calling*.) **Therefore, when you receive the ev_setup_done event and then issue an `infotag get evt_legs` info-tag command, the incoming leg is returned.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this works only if the destination is a number, I am dialing a pilot number (two or more numbers with single pilot number) and check the outgoing leg. Do you know how to do that? BTW, I can't ignore calling a pilot number. Thansk